# Как отправить поток микрофона на SHOUTCAST сервер

Tags: java, streaming

Я понимаю что отправка потока осуществляется так -
Открываем сокет
Отправляем данные
Авторизовываемся
Отправляем мета данные 
В этот же сокет отправляем поток аудио

Вот этот код

```
Socket s = new Socket("141.4.209.112", 8088);
Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");
OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
Log.d("VS", "Output Stream Established");
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
Log.d("VS", "Send Header");
output.println("SOURCE /app ICE/2.3.3");
output.println("content-type: audio/mpeg");
output.println("Authorization: Basic c291cmNlOmhhY2ttZQ==");
output.println("icy-name: Server");
output.println("icy-genre: Rock");
output.println("icy-bitrate: 128");
output.println("icy-private: 0");
output.println("icy-public: 1");
output.println("icy-audio-info: icy-samplerate=44100;icy-bitrate=128;icy-    channels=2");
output.println("");
output.flush();
Log.d("VS", "Header sent");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    s.getInputStream()));
String response = reader.readLine();
Log.v(LOG_TAG, response);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet httpGET = new HttpGet(
    "http://141.4.209.112:8088/admin.cgi?pass=hackme&mode=updinfo&mount=/app&song=akon");
httpGET.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic c291cmNlOmhhY2ttZQ==");
httpGET.setHeader("User-Agent", "(Mozilla Compatible)");

HttpResponse metaDataResponse = client.execute(httpGET);

System.out.println("Response Code : "
    + metaDataResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    metaDataResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
result.append(line);
}
```

Выполняется полностью, обновляет данные сонг (добавляет новый) но непонятно как отправить поток.

А вот этот код

```
s = new Socket(SP_url, 8088);
s.setSoTimeout(5000);
System.out.println("Streaming -> Socket open");
OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
System.out.println("Streaming -> Get output");
String user_agent = "WinampMPEG/5.09";
String req="GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+SP_url+"/\r\nuser-agent: "+user_agent+"\r\nIcy-MetaData: 1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
os.write(req.getBytes());
System.out.println("Streaming -> Send GET");
InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
System.out.println("Streaming -> Get Input");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));                          

int bitrate = 0;

String line = br.readLine();
String lines = "";
while(line != null && !line.isEmpty()){
    lines = lines + line;
    if(line.contains("icy-br"))
    {
        try{
            bitrate = Integer.parseInt(line.split(":")[1].trim());
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Streaming -> Error parsing bitrate");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("["+line+"]");
    line = br.readLine();   
}
//---------------------------------------UPDATE SONG
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
System.out.println("Streaming -> Create GET request");
HttpGet httpGET = new HttpGet(
        "http://"+SP_url+":8088/admin.cgi?"
                + "pass="+SP_pass+"&"
                + "mode=updinfo&url=http://"+SP_url+":8088/&song=O111");
httpGET.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic c291cmNlOmhhY2ttZQ==");
httpGET.setHeader("User-Agent", "(Mozilla Compatible)");
HttpResponse metaDataResponse = client.execute(httpGET);
System.out.println("Streaming -> Send UPDATE Song");


System.out.println("Response Code : "
        + metaDataResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

//---------------------------------------
System.out.println("Open Socket");
os.write("gf677nvc\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("icy-name:name1\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("icy-genre:genre1\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("icy-pub:0\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("icy-br:128000\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("icy-url:http://ricco.com\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("icy-irc:NONE1\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("icy-icq:NONE1\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("icy-aim:NONE1\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("content-type:audio/aacp\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("icy-reset:1\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("\r\n".getBytes());            
input = s.getInputStream();
//---------------------------------------
System.out.println("Streaming -> END");
```

Я получаю ответ сервера от сокета - 401 на порту 8088 и 402 на порту 8089 и 200OK на порту 8000. Но на порту 8000 ничего нет. Винамп соединяется с портом 8088 без проблем.

Может кто подскажет как это сделать ? отправить поток с микрофона на сервер?

Answer (score 0):

Все заработало - оказалось необходимо указать правильный HTTP заголовок

нашел на сайте мозилла

```
String req="GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                        + "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:40.0) Gecko/40.0 Firefox/40.0\r\n"
                        + "icy-metadata:1\r\n"
                        + "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
                os.write(req.getBytes());
```

стал получать ответ 200OK